An asymptotic formula in Apéry's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$
Let $a_n$ be the Apéry sequence
$$ 
a_n = \sum_{0\leq k\leq n}\binom{n}{k}^2\binom{n+k}{k}^2.
$$
Reading the 1978 paper Démonstration de l’irrationalité de $\zeta(3)$ (d’après R. Apery) of Cohen, at THEOREME 1 he states that $a_n \sim A \alpha^n n^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ for some constant $A>0$, where $\alpha=(1+\sqrt{2})^4$.
I've spent years trying to understand and proof why that's true, and although I've found some explanations related to some obscure and difficult theorems in the asymptotics of order 2 difference equations, it is not more satisfying to use some theorems whose proof I also don't understand.
So, if someone could give a more or less elementary proof of this asymptotic relation I'll be really, really grateful.
EDIT: I'll add a link to a work I did (Desde el problema de Basilea al teorema de Apéry)  explaining in detail Apéry's proof where the only detail missing is the one I'm asking for (but it is in Spanish).

Self-contained posts are much preferable -- especially in this case, your link is insecure, according to my browser.

Have you looked at Beukers' version of the proof? It is simpler and avoids the asymptotic you struggle with: https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/11.3.268

@IosifPinelis It is a link to numdam, so I don't know why it says its insecure...

@GHfromMO I know about that proof but some years ago I wrote some notes explaining in detail Apéry's original proof (which I think it has not being done in that detail, but I haven't linked it because it is in spanish) and that's the only detail I didn't managed to explain. So I'm a little bit frustated and ansious about it :(

@IosifPinelis, it's saying link is insecure since numdam seems to be using http:// not https:// (fully encrypted link)

One way is to use the recurrence relation $(n+1)^3a_{n+1}-(34n^3+51n^2+27n+5)a_n+n^3a_{n-1}=0$ that Cohen proves as Proposition 1, and then use e.g. the Birkhoff-Adams theorem to deduce an asymptotic from this second-order recurrence relation. But presumably this is exactly the kind of proof you were ruling out, and wanted a proof not via the recurrence relation?

This is just an idea: I guess that some "middle terms" of positive density would contribute to the actual sum and the other tail terms might be negligible. When $k = \beta n$, one can use Stirling's formula to approximate the $k$-th term as
$$
\frac{1+\beta}{\beta^2(1-\beta)} \frac{1}{\pi n} \gamma^n
$$
where
$$
\gamma = \frac{(1 + \beta)^2}{\beta^{\frac{4 + 2\beta}{1+\beta}}(1-\beta)^{2-2\beta}}
$$
(maybe the computation is wrong). Not sure how to proceed from here (especially how to related this with the $\alpha = (1+\sqrt{2})^4$ in the paper)

@ThomasBloom Yes, that's the proof I have but using Birkhoff-Adams theorem as a black box and I don't know any good (and accesible for non-experts) book or paper where the theorem is proved. That's one of the reasons I'd like a proof without using the recurrence relation, but a good source for a proof of Birkhoff-Adams theorem would also be appreciated (I know the articles of Wong and Li, but they are too advanced for me in this topic).

another way to get the asymptotic is to consider the ODE satisfied by $\sum a_nz^n$; it is listed on the sequence OEIS A005259 page, though it is really straightforward to deduce from the recurrence with a little experience (eg must be degree $3$ but the leading polynomial must be degree $4$ etc; then as the leading coefficient is $z^2(z^2-34z+1)$ and the power series has a singularity on its radius of convergence which is obviously at most $1$, it follows that the radius is precisely the smaller root $\beta$ of $z^2-34z+1$ which gives the exponential asymptotic $(1/\beta)^n$

next the symbol at $\beta$ is $(0,1,1/2)$ (immediate from the form of the equation) and the solution at $\beta$ for exponent $0$ is analytic like for exponent $1$ (this last is automatic from Frobenius theory) from the form of the ODE, so the original power series must have $(z-\beta)^{1/2}h(z)$ near $\beta$ in its linear combination in terms of solutions at $\beta$ hence the $n^{-3/2}$ finer asymptotic as that is the square root coefficient asymptotic

The general method of dealing with such sums is using de Moivre - Laplace central limit theorem.
We start with finding $\alpha$ by the following reasoning. We have ${n\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\leqslant 1$ and ${n+k\choose k}y^k(1-y)^n\leqslant 1$ for all $x,y\in [0,1]$ (both expressions in LHS are certain binomial probabilities). Thus, $${n\choose k}{n+k\choose k}\leqslant x^{-k}(1-x)^{k-n}y^{-k}(1-y)^{-n}.$$
This does not depend on $k$ if $y=(1-x)/x$, so let it be the case (and automatically $x>1/2$). Both binomial probabilities are not too small if simultaneously $k\sim xn$ and $k\sim y(n+k)$, equivalently, $$1/x\sim n/k=(n+k)/k-1=1/y-1=(2x-1)/(1-x).$$ So, $x$ must solve the equation $1/x=(2x-1)/(1-x)$, i.e., $x=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $y=\sqrt{2}-1$. Then the bound reads
$$
{n\choose k}{n+k\choose k}\leqslant ((1-x)(1-y))^{-n}=(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n}.$$
For finding more precise asymptotics we use de Moivre - Laplace asymptotics
$$
{n\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\sim \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n x(1-x)}}e^{-\frac{(k-nx)^2}{2nx(1-x)}}\\
{n+k\choose k}y^k(1-y)^{n-k}\sim \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi (n+k) y(1-y)}}e^{-\frac{(k-(n+k)y)^2}{2(n+k)y(1-y)}}, 
$$
which are precise unless the probabilities are too small to have impact on the whole sum (to be concrete, in the regime $|k-nx|<n^{3/5}$ the equivalences hold uniformly, and $k$ outside this range give only few superpolynomially smaller terms).
Since $k-(n+k)y=(1-y)(k-nx)$, after multiplying these equivalences we get something like $${n\choose k}{n+k\choose k}\sim \frac{A}{n}(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n}e^{-B(k-nx)^2/n}$$
for some explicit constants $A,B$, it remains to take the square and replace the sum $$A^2\sum_{k\colon |k-nx|<n^{3/5}}n^{-2}(1+\sqrt{2})^{4n}e^{-2B(k-nx)^2/n}$$ by the integral
$$A^2\int_{\tau\colon |\tau-nx|<n^{3/5}}n^{-2}(1+\sqrt{2})^{4n}e^{-2B(\tau-nx)^2/n}d\tau$$ to get the result of the form $Cn^{-3/2}(1+\sqrt{2})^{4n}$, with explicit $C$ (if you care, I may find this $C$).
But does such sharp asymptotics really matters, or only the value of $\alpha$?

Could you please elaborate more the last part? I don't see how to sum all the products of the binomials and mantain the asymptotics (I've never done any calculations like these ones) and I don"t understad what you mean by replacing the sum by an integral

The sum of $\exp(-B(k-nx)^2/n)$ over $k$ is a Riemann sum of the integral $\int_0^n \exp(-B(\tau-nx)^2/n)d\tau$, thus they are close enough, in the integral pass to a new variable $\theta:=(\tau -nx)\sqrt{B/n}$

But why summing over the product of the binomials is asymptotic to the sum of the terms on the right?

You may sum up asymptotic equivalences of positive values. This is common sense (if in each family the husband and the wife earn almost equally, then the total salaries of men and women are also almost equal).

But the sum is not with a fixed number of factors, they grow as you make n go to infinity.

When equivalences are uniform, you may sum up as many as you wish. Say, if in each family the salaries differ by at most one percent, then the same holds for the total salaries of (married) men/women, independently on how many pairs are there. In our situation the equivalences are uniform in a wide range like $|k-nx|<n^{3/5}$, the terms outside this range are too small to have an influence at asymptotics
